# Add value to field using Entity Metadata Wrapper

Tags: 7, entities

I'm trying to accomplish the seemingly simple task to add a value to a multi-value file field in Drupal 7. I have been trying for hours, but none of the answers I found would solve my problem.

My field is called `field_video_ext`. Using the [Remote Stream Wrapper module](https://www.drupal.org/project/remote_stream_wrapper), I would like to add values like this (using some of the module's code):

```
<?php

// My videos and their respective nodes.
$videos = array(
  array(
    'nid' => '1903',
    'uri' => 'http://example.com/movie.flv',
  ),
  array(
    'nid' => '3172',
    'uri' => 'http://example.com/movie2.flv',
  ),
);

foreach ($videos as $video) {
  // From the Remote Stream Wrapper module.
  try {
    $file = remote_stream_wrapper_file_load_by_uri($video['uri']);
    if (!$file) {
      $file = remote_stream_wrapper_file_create_by_uri($video['uri']);
      file_save($file);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    drupal_set_message($e->getMessage());
  }

  if (empty($file->fid)) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Unable to add file from URL %file.', array('%file' => $video['uri'])));
    exit;
  }
  // Display needs to be set.
  $file->display = 1;

  // Get Entity Metadata Wrapper
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $video['nid']);

  // Write information into fields.
  $wrapper->field_video_ext->set(get_object_vars($file));

  // Save wrapper.
  $wrapper->save();

}

?>
```

Now the problem is that this doesn't work if the field accepts multiple values. It throws the error

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given for wrapper
>   chain

I then tried using `$wrapper->field_video_ext[] = get_object_vars($file);`, but that doesn't work either. I think it was this error I got:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Project as array

I also tried the following instead of `get_object_vars($file)`:

```
$file = (array) $file;
$items = array($file);
```

And then saving that array using `set()` or the `[]` way. But to no avail. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does your $file contain?

Comment: $file is a full file object returned by remote_stream_wrapper_file_create_by_uri(). I checked it against other files and it looks exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One issue may be that `get_object_vars()` returns an array with keys that the file field does not understand.  [The EntityMetadataWrapper documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers) provides two options for setting file reference values, though it appears to use single value fields in the examples:

Setting the file directly:

```
$w_containing_node->field_attachment_content->file->set( $file_obj );
```

Providing an array with just `fid`:

```
$w_containing_node->field_attachment_content->set( array('fid' => $fid) )
```

---

One of the comments provides the following examples from the entity tests which apply to a multi-value field, though I'm not sure if setting the full file object will work appending a new item:

```
$wrapper->field_file[0] = array('fid' => $file->fid, 'display' => TRUE);
$wrapper->field_file[1]->file = $file;
```

Comment: Using an array with just fid I get the mentioned "Invalid data value given" error. Setting the file directly through file->set(), I get "Call to a member function set() on a non-object" (both with $file being an object or an array). But ´$wrapper->field_video_ext[0] = array('fid' => $file->fid, 'display' => TRUE);´ seems to work. I'll re-check that and get back.

Comment: Looks good, so I guess $wrapper->field_video_ext[0] = array('fid' => $file->fid, 'display' => TRUE); is the right answer. Thanks!